# Using SFML on MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I've been working on a Gameboy emulator, and everything's looking great, I've already implemented the core, flag updates, cycle accurate interrupts, etc. I thought it was time to see something.

I chose SFML for the graphics, and, so far I was able to compile the example program. But, when I tried to compile my emulator, it seems that the actual C++ standard library was unlinked, as the log reports undefined references from STD methods, such as:

```
agb\main.o:main.cc:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `__ZSt4cout'
agb\main.o:main.cc:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `__ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev'
agb\main.o:main.cc:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `__ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev'
```

and, this particularly interesting one:

```
C:/Users/Astherix/Desktop/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

Anyone has a clue as to why this is happening?

I use a custom BAT to compile, this is the source:

```
@echo off
set name=%1
echo Started building project '%name%' through gcc.
echo Creating object file '%name%.o'...
g++ -c %name%.cc -IC:\Users\Astherix\Desktop\mingw64\sfml\include
echo Compiling executable '%name%.exe'...
g++  %name%.o -o %name%.exe -LC:\Users\Astherix\Desktop\mingw64\sfml\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try moving the `%name%.o` after the `-o %name%.exe` but before the libraries?

Comment: like `g++  -o %name%.exe %name%.o -LC:\Users\Astherix\Desktop\mingw64\sfml\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`?

Comment: Same luck, though

Comment: Does a basic `#include <iostream>\n int main(){std::cout << "Hello World\n";}` compile?

Comment: Or try adding the flag `g++ -x c++ ... etc...`?

Comment: I solved the problem, it seems that because the source was on a folder inside /bin, it wouldnt compile (??), I dont know why, but when compiling the source within /bin, it works :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source code is within a folder, you might want to move it to the same folder g++, c++ or whatever compiler you're using is in. Or just make a copy-move script of sorts.